# On every try I am getting last fetched ID , help me fix it please

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code on the one side

```
<tbody>
                                <? 
                      $select_main = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM channels WHERE parent_id=$package_id ORDER BY id ASC");
                      while($row_main = $select_main->fetch_object()){
                      ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="this_id" value="<? echo $row_main->id; ?>" class="form-control"></td>
                                    <td><? echo $row_main->name; ?></td>
                                    <td><? echo $row_main->type; ?></td>
                                    <td><img src="../logos/<? echo $row_main->logo;?>" style="width: 30px;"></td>
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" name="delete_vacancy">არხის წაშლა</button></td>
                                    <td><input type="file" name="image"> </td>
                                    <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-block" name="update_logo">ლოგოს განახლება</button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <? } ?>
                            </tbody>

if(isset($_POST["update_logo"])){
    $channel_id = $_POST['this_id'];
$sql = "UPDATE channels SET logo='3333' WHERE id=$channel_id";
         mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

every time it brings up the last id from that fetch, can you help me resolve it?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Do you have _one_ form element surrounding your table?

Comment: You have a loop to retrieve the relevant records, but you have assigned the different values of `id` to multiple fields using the same name (this_id) ! One of the ways is to fix it : pass the $row_main->id thru GET when the user click the hyperlink

Comment: Yes, there is a form surrounding a table.

@KenLee Can you explain it in more details please?

Comment: If you have one form, you'll submit multiple elements with `name="this_id"`  - last one is the one taken. Instead, place a form for every row in your loop

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injection attack - always use a prepared statement when using user supplied data with sql